# Настройка базы данных Word Press

Tags: wordpress

У меня сделан сайт на локальном хосте, нужно перенести его на платный хостинг. 
Если кто-то сталкивался, как это можно сделать в файле 
wp-config.php без потери инфы .

Имя базы данных 
Имя базы данных для WordPress
Пароль к базе данных 
Имя сервера базы данных

Comment: прописывайте новые параметры и все будет работать

Answer (score 0):

Это лучше и безопасней делать с помощью плагинов для миграции/клонирования. Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ 
Если будет ругаться на большой архив - можно исключить некоторые объёмные каталоги (напр uploads) и перенести их потом вручную.